# Resume title formatting

Tags: graphics, header-footer, titles, fontsize, fontawesome

So currently this puts everything into one line but I want my name to be much bigger and preferabbly the phone and email start from right not equally spaced from name. I still want everything to be in one line but way more professional. What are some suggestions? Also I am thinking of having my photo in the upper left corner as I have been suggested having a photo makes things more natural and interviewers prefer it. However is that true? And if that's the case what is the tex template to do so?

```
\begin{document}

\reversemarginpar 
\setlength\marginparwidth{0.9in}
\newcommand{\LHEAD}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{\large\scshape#1}}

%\bigskip

    \begin{tabular}{rl}
             Mona Jalal 
                Cell Phone: (+1) xyz xyz xyzy
            & E-mail: \href{mailto:jalal@cs.wisc.edu}{jalal@cs.wisc.edu} 
    \end{tabular}
```

Comment: your example is not clear as a. it lacks `\documentclass` and b. it cannot run (lacking `\end{document}` - and maybe other stuff ?) please try to make your minimal working example working... That aside, take a look at http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear which document class you are using but if I understand your question right, this should do what you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft}X<{}}
\begin{document}
\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lR}
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{demo}&\\
             \multicolumn{1}{c}{\LARGE Mona Jalal} &
                Cell Phone: (+1) xyz xyz xyzy
E-mail: \href{mailto:jalal@cs.wisc.edu}{jalal@cs.wisc.edu} 
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

If you are looking to write a resume, I think it would be better to use [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) or other similar document classes.

> ... I have been suggested having a photo makes things more natural and interviewers prefer it. However is that true?

I am not sure really. I personally would not bother with having a photo in my resume but if you are looking to work in academia, you can ask your question on [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) and see what other people suggest.

> And if that's the case what is the tex template to do so?

Look at the examples of `moderncv` class; it should provide what you need.